# Spark subquery optimum approach

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hive

I have a spark sub query on hive table:  `select * from table where id in (select id from table b)` Would this be executed by spark in one go or will it be done in two separate fetches? If two then where will be the data be stored temporarily? The table has millions of data generated per minute. I would like to know what the optimum approach is and the query mentioned above is failing or taking a lot of time.

Comment: Try an explain.